# Q: How do I turn off auto-preview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, preview

Android Studio IDE breaking GUI issue image at - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEKFo.jpg

My Android Studio is showing one or more preview windows generated at the position of the cursor in the Code Editor window. This preview overlays the original work behind it and pretty much renders my entire IDE useless or near useless. Although the preview will disappear upon mousing over portions of it, only to reappear seconds later. Is there some auto-preview window option that might be turned on by default that I have missed entirely?

I apologize if this has been asked before - I had not been able to find the answer previously and this has completely halted my development.

UPDATE: Restarting Android Studio, restarting my machine, and re-installing Android Studio all result in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check enable: File > Power Save Mode

Hope this helps